# Снипеты / алиасы

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, подкиньте идею как реализовать следующее: к примеру, в админ панели в какую-либо сущность в описание вставлю снипет или алиас такого вида `[ title ]`, и при этом хочу чтобы на сайте этому снипету назначились определенные данные.

т.е. как обработать такие переменные перед выводом?

Comment: Почему не используешь Smarty? Ну или другой движок шаблонизации? Конечно ты можешь ознакомиться с построением шаблонизатора самостоятельно, но, если задача имеет сроки - лучше использовать проверенное решение.

Comment: Юзал я и Smarty и Twig, но возьмем к примеру Twig, вставив в админке {{ title }} он так и отобразит его, как строку а не переменную.

Comment: @dogmar, я нее знаком с Twig'ом, но посмотрев сайт по-быстрому пришел к тому, что он, кроме синтаксиса, ничем от смарти то и не отличается. Скорее всего ты где-то ошибся при использовании. Или я тебя не до конца понял.

Comment: Ты меня не доконца понял, что твиг что смарти по сути делают одно и тоже, у меня кое что другое, в админке я заношу в текстовую форму такую метку {{ title }} после она хронится в базе и выводится во фронте, но перед этим строковое значение {{ title }} переопределяется на то значение которое я захочу, такое в вордпрессе есть, к примеру создал плагин он сгенерировал алиас [ slider 56 ]. вставил ты его в любое место, и в шаблоне он развернулся в слайдер

Comment: так смарти и твиг могут разворачивать шаблоны из строки. в чем проблема ?

Comment: в вордпрессе это шорткоды. каждая запись проходит специальный фильтр, который парсит на их наличие (регекспами и тд). Перед этим данный шорткод должен быть зарегестрирован (объявлен) и к нему привязана определенная функция на выполнение, которая будет возвращать что-либо вместо шорткода (в Вашем случае строку с заголовком).

Comment: по сути, Вам нужно почти то же, но немного проще. если у вас кол-во шорткодов типа [title] и тд ограничено, то нет нужды в впшных регистрациях и тд (там это сделано для гибкости). Вам достаточно регулярными выражениями парсить контент на наличие такого шорткода, если есть, то, основываясь на текущем айди поста (или что там у вас) вытащить из базы нужный тайтл...